# how to trigger capybara's automatic AJAX waiting without using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

Under **Asynchronous Javascript**, the capybara README gives the following example of something that will wait for Ajax:

```
page.should have_text('baz')
```

That's an RSpec construct, but I'm using Test::Unit + shoulda.   What's the equivalent in Test::Unit/shoulda?   This is my code:

```
assert_equal 'foo', find('.bar').text
```

The line previous to that triggers an Ajax event.   My assertion will succeed if executed after the ajax completes but fails if before.   How do I tell it to keep retrying until it either succeeds or exceeds Capybara.default_wait_time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capybara mailing list worked better than Stack Overflow even though it took the moderators over 24 hours to approve my post because of Turkey Day.   Here is [Jonas Nicklas' response](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/b5b4005740017b72):

```
assert page.has_text?('test')
```

note that the negative form is:

```
assert page.has_no_text?('test')
```

and NOT:

```
assert !page.has_text?('test')
```

this is WRONG, don't do this. RSpec nowadays doesn't have this problem
anymore, so its safe to do:

```
page.should_not have_text('test')
```

/Jonas

Answer (score 3):

I use **capybara and Selenium** and `wait_until` **after clicking somewhere or visiting a new path**:

```
somebutton.click
wait_until { something to be true }
```

**or**

```
somebutton.click
wait_until(n) { something to be true }
```

where "n" is the number of seconds to wait

Comment: Note that most asserts in Capybara do a wait and an assert.   Two birds in one stone, making for much more readable code.

Comment: The use of wait_until is discouraged, see http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara

Answer (score 0):

I did also figure something else that worked.   I prefer Jonas' answer, but this also works:

```
 assert find('.bar:contains("foo")')
```

The assertion is not necessary since the find throws an exception on
failure, it just documents that this is a test.